# How to revoke a function-call access key?

Tags: nearprotocol

"Access keys are stored as account_id,public_key in a trie state."
how do I revoke an function-call access key from the blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove an access key by sending a `DeleteKey` transaction. For more details on transactions, please checkout [this page](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/transaction#docsNav).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would delete an access key for `example.testnet`:

```js
const { KeyPair, keyStore, connect } = require("near-api-js");

const CREDENTIALS_DIR = "~/.near-credentials";
const ACCOUNT_ID = "example.testnet";
const PUBLIC_KEY = "8hSHprDq2StXwMtNd43wDTXQYsjXcD4MJTXQYsjXcc";
const keyStore = new keyStores.UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore(CREDENTIALS_DIR);

const config = {
  keyStore,
  networkId: "testnet",
  nodeUrl: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
};

deleteAccessKey(ACCOUNT_ID, PUBLIC_KEY);

async function deleteAccessKey(accountId, publicKey) {
  const near = await connect(config);
  const account = await near.account(accountId);
  await account.deleteKey(publicKey);
}
```

You will need to make sure you have credentials for your account stored locally to complete this function. Do this by running the following [`near-cli`](https://github.com/near/near-cli) command:

```sh
near login
```

For more info on rotating access keys, check out this doc:

https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#access-key-rotation